# ITMS-90430: Invalid Swift Support - The file myFile.dylib doesn’t have a signing ID

Tags: ios, code-signing, appstore-approval, dylib

When submitting an app containing a dylib file, I get this error message:

**ITMS-90430: Invalid Swift Support - The file myFile.dylib doesn’t have a signing ID. Sign the file, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.**

Trying to signing the file using:
`codesign -s <identity> <code-path>`

But I keep getting the same error message.
What is the correct way to sign the file to be accepted?

For more details: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711548

Answer (score 1):

It seems AppStore doesn't accept apps with dylib file embedded. I met the same issue before and solved it by converting the library to a framework bundle.